# PHP Captcha didnt work

Tags: php, captcha

I having problem with my captcha method, the char code does not work.

This is my code that I have so far:

```
<?php
    class captcha 
    {
        function genCaptcha()
        {
            $temp;
            $tempCap = "";
            for ($i=1; $i <= 6 ; $i++) 
            { 
                if ($i%2 == 1) $temp = floor(rand()*10);
                else $temp = chr(floor(rand()*26)+65);

                $tempCap = $tempCap + $temp;
            }
            echo $tempCap;
        }
    }

    $asd = new captcha();
    $asddd = $asd->genCaptcha();
?>
```

It is supposed to echo like this `4A7D0Z` (which will display a random captcha when you refresh the page). How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Seems to be off-topic because you try to recruit debug staff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
$tempCap = $tempCap + $temp;
```

You are trying to add strings together. Adding strings together in PHP is done with a period instead of +-sign.

```
$tempCap = $tempCap . $temp;
```

This should be correct.

Comment: wow, thas work. thank you jeroen,
i didnt put my attention to that. thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to vote my answer as correct, so other people won't try to break their heads on an already answered question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will allow you to adjust the weights of the values being joined.

**Edited**

The benefit of this route, is that you can omit characters that may pose problems - such as 0 to O, I to l to 1, and so forth.

```
<?php
    class captcha 
    {

        /*
         * These should total 100
         */

        private $weightNumber = 44;
        private $weightUpper = 20;
        private $weightLower = 36;

        public $tempcap;

        private $capLen = 6;

        private $lower  = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        private $upper  = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        private $number = '0123456789';


        function genCaptcha()
        {
            $tempCap = "";

            $blocks = array();

            /*
             * These blocks are multiplied by numbers to equal 260 characters, to provide even weighting.
             */

            $blocks[] = str_repeat($this->lower, $this->weightLower * 10);  // sum 260
            $blocks[] = str_repeat($this->upper, $this->weightUpper * 10);  // sum 260
            $blocks[] = str_repeat($this->number, $this->weightNumber * 26);  // sum 260

            /*
             * Strings are joined, and then split into an array of individual characters.
             */

            $seed = str_split( implode('', $blocks) );



            /*
             * Loop over the number of items in the captcha block
             */

            for ($i = 0; $i < $this->capLen; $i++) {

                /*
                 * Concatenate a random element from the 'shuffled' array using `mt_rand()`, a better random generator in PHP
                 */ 

                shuffle($seed);

                $rkey     = mt_rand(1,count($seed));
                $tempCap .= $seed[$rkey];
                unset($seed[$rkey]);

            }

            /* 
             * Echo the generated CAPTCHA, probably better to do this as a returned var
             */

            $this->tempcap = implode('', $seed);

            return $tempCap;
        }
    }

    $asd = new captcha();

    // Here you could (if you chose to return from class method), do `echo $asd->genCaptcha();`

    $asddd = $asd->genCaptcha();

    echo $asddd;


    preg_match_all('([a-z]{1}+)', $asddd, $lowermatches);
    preg_match_all('([A-Z]{1}+)', $asddd, $uppermatches);
    preg_match_all('([0-9]{1}+)', $asddd, $numbermatches);

    echo '<br/>';echo '<br/>';echo '<br/>';

    echo 'Lowercase ('.count($lowermatches[0]).'): ' . round(100 * count($lowermatches[0])/strlen($asddd),1) . '%';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'Uppercase ('.count($uppermatches[0]).'): ' . round(100 * count($uppermatches[0])/strlen($asddd),1) . '%';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'Numerics ('.count($numbermatches[0]).'): ' . round(100 * count($numbermatches[0])/strlen($asddd),1) . '%';



    preg_match_all('([a-z]{1}+)', $asd->tempcap, $lowermatches);
    preg_match_all('([A-Z]{1}+)', $asd->tempcap, $uppermatches);
    preg_match_all('([0-9]{1}+)', $asd->tempcap, $numbermatches);

    echo '<br/>';echo '<br/>';echo '<br/>';

// var_dump($matches[0]);
    echo 'Lowercase ('.count($lowermatches[0]).'): ' . round(100 * count($lowermatches[0])/strlen($asd->tempcap),1) . '%';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'Uppercase ('.count($uppermatches[0]).'): ' . round(100 * count($uppermatches[0])/strlen($asd->tempcap),1) . '%';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'Numerics ('.count($numbermatches[0]).'): ' . round(100 * count($numbermatches[0])/strlen($asd->tempcap),1) . '%';

 ?>
```

**Output**

```
jzt76W

Lowercase (3): 50%
Uppercase (1): 16.7%
Numerics (2): 33.3%

Lowercase (9357): 36%
Uppercase (5199): 20%
Numerics (11438): 44%
```

The rest is up to you!

**Update**

See example here, with demo of percentage of numbers from sample string:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/hip3iN

Comment: Note - as with any probability type function - the accuracy of what you are aiming for will increase as you increase the sample size. So, as you increase the length of the captcha, it will be more representative of your desired weights.

Comment: wow, this is very useful help. I will implement to my captcha ASAP. Thank you very much mr barry for helping my problem.